# Error in wrap-up: Object not found, user defined function

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write a function that produces some summary statistics and makes some plots for very specific data. However, when I try to run the function the plots fail to be produced and I get the following error:

Error during wrapup: object 'ff' not found. From a variety of testing, I can tell that the error is coming from the plotting part of the function. I've also asked the function to print this object independent of the plot, which it has done with no problem, so I am not really sure what the problem is.

This is probably something really obvious that I am missing, but I can't see, to figure it out. I am posting my code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here is a bit of sample data that I pass through my function, the relevant columns are "FISH", "FARM", and "MIX". The function is also included below:

```
humans_l[[2004]]
        PB.HAP.Grp             Chem Lake.Dist..m. Wsp..ms.1. Precip..mm.
1 Mercury (methyl) Mercury (methyl)            40        2.8        1500
2 Mercury (methyl) Mercury (methyl)            40        2.8        1500
3 Mercury (methyl) Mercury (methyl)            40        2.8        1500
4 Mercury (methyl) Mercury (methyl)            40        2.8        1500
  CHRIS.Lake_WSP_PRECIP  MIX Ratio..ThreshT2.ThreshT1. Ratio..EEFT1.EEFT2. Farm.Fraction
1           40_2.8_1500  710                  10.53022                   1   0.001876256
2           40_2.8_1500  865                  11.12440                   1   0.001644249
3           40_2.8_1500 1079                  11.98686                   1   0.001434138
4           40_2.8_1500 1537                  13.91867                   1   0.001182803
  Fish.Fraction        FARM       FISH Soil.Fraction Exposed.Vegetable.Fraction
1     0.9981237 0.000178178 0.09478657   0.000307563                0.000190690
2     0.9983558 0.000147806 0.08974468   0.000269257                0.000167158
3     0.9985659 0.000119642 0.08330503   0.000234640                0.000145833
4     0.9988172 0.000085000 0.07176095   0.000193304                0.000120313
  Protected.Vegetable.Fraction Exposed.Fruit.Fraction Protected.Fruit.Fraction
1                  0.000180819            0.000258604              0.000826058
2                  0.000158505            0.000226691              0.000724117
3                  0.000138284            0.000197772              0.000631742
4                  0.000114085            0.000163162              0.000521189
  Root.Vegetable.Fraction Beef.Fraction Total.Dairy.Fraction Pork.Fraction
1                9.10e-06      6.38e-05             2.58e-05      8.85e-08
2                7.98e-06      5.58e-05             2.26e-05      7.75e-08
3                6.96e-06      4.87e-05             1.97e-05      6.75e-08
4                5.74e-06      4.01e-05             1.62e-05      5.56e-08
  Poultry.Fraction Eggs.Fraction
1         5.65e-06      8.05e-06
2         4.94e-06      7.05e-06
3         4.31e-06      6.14e-06
4         3.55e-06      5.06e-0

names(humans_l[2004])
"Mercury (methyl)40_2.8_1500"

    regr<-function(dataframe, name){
  require(ggplot2)
  require(ggthemes)
  require(reshape2)

  pr_farm<-lm(log(dataframe$FARM)~log(dataframe$MIX))
  farm_intercept<-as.numeric(summary(pr_farm)$coefficients[1,1])
  farm_slope<-as.numeric(summary(pr_farm)$coefficients[2,1])
  b<-confint(pr_farm, 'log(dataframe$MIX)', level=0.95)
  CI_farm<-summary(pr_farm)$coefficients[2,1]-b[1]
  r.square_farm<-summary(pr_farm)$r.squared

  if(dataframe$FISH[1] != 0) {
    pr_fish<-lm(log(dataframe$FISH)~log(dataframe$MIX))
    fish_intercept<-as.numeric(summary(pr_fish)$coefficients[1,1])
    fish_slope<-as.numeric(summary(pr_fish)$coefficients[2,1])
    a<-confint(pr_fish, 'log(dataframe$MIX)', level=0.95)
    CI_fish<-summary(pr_fish)$coefficients[2,1]-a[1]
    r.square_fish<-summary(pr_fish)$r.squared
  } else {
    fish_intercept<-NA
    fish_slope<-NA
    CI_fish<-NA
    r.square_fish<-NA
  }



  vector<-c(farm_intercept, farm_slope, CI_farm, r.square_farm, fish_intercept, fish_slope, CI_fish, r.square_fish)
  names(vector)<-c("farm_intercept", "farm_slope", "CI_farm", "r.squared_farm", "fish_intercept", "fish_slope", "CI_fish", "r.squared_fish")

  print(formatC(vector, format="f", digits=5))

  Farm<-data.frame(x=dataframe$MIX, y=dataframe$FARM)
  Fish<-data.frame(x=dataframe$MIX, y=dataframe$FISH)
  ff <- melt(list(Farm=Farm, Fish=Fish), id.vars = "x")
  plot1<-ggplot(ff, aes(x=x, y=value, color=L1, fill=L1))+geom_point(aes(x=ff$x, y=Farm$value, color=ff$L1), shape=19, size=7)+geom_point(size=6, shape=21, lwd=4)+scale_fill_manual("Risk Type", values=c("Farm"="#677719", "Fish"="#0067AB"))+scale_colour_manual("Risk Type", values=c("Farm"="darkgreen", "Fish"="darkblue"))
  plot2<-plot1+theme_classic()
  plot3<-plot2+scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(710, 865, 1079, 1537))+xlab("Mixing Height")+ylab("Tier 2 Risk")
  plot4<-plot3+geom_line(aes(y=exp(farm_intercept)*x^farm_slope), color="darkgreen", lwd=2, lty=1)
  plot6<-plot4+theme(axis.title=element_text())+theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face='bold', size=20),axis.title.y = element_text(face='bold', size=20, angle=90) )
  plot7<-plot6+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face='bold', size=18),axis.text.y = element_text(face='bold', size=18) )
  plot8<-plot7+theme(axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=0.25))
  plot9<-plot8+ggtitle(name)
  ggsave(paste(name, '.pdf', sep=""), plot1)
  postscript(file = paste(name, '.eps', sep=""))
  dev.off()

  print(plot9)
}
```

And this is the output/error I get:

```
regr(humans_l[[2004]], name=names(humans_l[2004]))
    farm_intercept     farm_slope        CI_farm r.squared_farm fish_intercept     fish_slope 
        "-2.33663"     "-0.95878"      "0.01370"      "0.99998"      "0.03835"     "-0.36312" 
           CI_fish r.squared_fish 
         "0.10279"      "0.99142" 
    Saving 11.2 x 8.28 in image
    Error during wrapup: object 'Farm' not found
```

The image that prints is blank due to the error. I can't see what I am doing wrong! Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks very much!!